# Ajax https is not applied in the laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, https, routes

laravel ver 9
url connecting now https://www.com
ajax code url:http://www.com

routes/web.php

```
route::get('/file/{doc_id}/research_list', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'research_list'])->name('research_filelist');
```

``

blade.php code

```
  $(document).on("click", "#Recently_Uploadhistory_{{ $laboratory_documents->id }}", function() {
                                         document.getElementById("data_wait_{{ $laboratory_documents->id }}").innerHTML =
                                             loading_list;

                                         $.ajax({
                                             url: '{{ Route('research_filelist', $laboratory_documents->id) }}',
                                             type: 'GET',
                                             processData: false,
                                             contentType: false,
                                             
                                             success: function(data) {
                                                 
                                                 $("#data_wait_{{ $laboratory_documents->id }}").empty();

                                                
                                                 document.getElementById(
                                                         "data_wait_{{ $laboratory_documents->id }}")
                                                     .innerHTML =
                                                     data;
                                                 console.log(data);
                                             }
                                         });
                                     });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZqC4.png)
https please

cloudflare
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqOe3.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the route() helper like this in your ajax url:

```
{{ route('research_filelist', ['doc_id' => $laboratory_documents->id]) }}
```